# Windows 10 - Enable logging for printing

Tags: printing, printer, windows-10

My computer (with windows 10) is not printing on a printer (model: OKI C310dn) and I can not identify the problem. On the manufacturers website there is no appropriate driver for windows 10. I've used the driver from the printers driver-disc which doesn't mention any compability.

So my question is: How can I find out what causes this trouble? I know of the event log, but can't see any printer related entries.

Some other information:

- the printer is listed as a printer among printers
- the printers driver install was successfull
- the website of the printer can be accessed (web interface)
- printer status says "ok"
- other computers can print on this printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the website they recently added info for Windows 10 drivers. Link is below:
http://www.okidata.com/resources/driver/Win10_Compatibility_List-V1.0.pdf

Have you tried their customer support? They are usually quick in helping with these requests.